# How to add copy link location in custom context menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, right-click, contextmenu

I'm developing an asp.net mvc 3 web application. Here I need to add custom context menu. So I have disabled the default right click context and added a plugin for custom context menu.

I'm trying to add an item in the custom menu, namely: "Copy link location". Which is available in browsers.

However the problem is, how can I detect that the user right clicked on a html link? Because the context menu appears by clicking anywhere on the webpage. And 
also, how can I copy that specific link location? What is the javascript behind getting a link location from a document?

Answer (score 0):

See [Dynamic Right Click Context Menu](http://ajaxian.com/archives/dynamic-right-click-context-menu) for adding custom right click context menu.

For getting the URL of the link you have selected, all you need to get is

`anchor.getAttribute("href")`